# Unity Rigidbody2d AddTorque with drag by touch

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to spin a wheel by dragging it with touch or mouse. I have used this code before but now I am trying to use it on a Rigidbody2d and with touch.

I get an error `Argument:1 cannot convert UnityEngine.Vector3 to float` on both the `rb.AddTorque`

```
public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    rb.AddTorque(Vector3.up * torque * -Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"));

    rb.AddTorque(Vector3.right * torque * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));
}
```

Comment: Its either `Rigidbody.AddTorque(Vector3, ForceMode)` or `Rigidbody2D.AddTorgue(float, ForceMode2D)`. Its only logical, you dont need more than one value in 2D ;) https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddTorque.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official unity docs state that Add Torque for 2D rigidbodies takes in only a float and optionally a force mode like this:

```
public void AddTorque(float torque, ForceMode2D mode = ForceMode2D.Force);
```

You get an error because you are trying to pass in a Vector3 where a float is expected.

Answer (score 0):

According to [AddTorque](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html) documentation, it should be taking a Vector3 fine, unless you were to pass in three parameters. But that is for 2019.2.

I would take a look at it's parameter type to verify (in VS, ctrl+shift+space while cursor is within argument list). And also make sure that torque is a float.

Comment: its a rigidbody2D. in 2D space there is no need for more than one value.